# Google Charts -- Chart not changing on selection

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

In a PHP page I am creating a table using tablesorter, showing and hiding a child row. When a row in the table is clicked, the child row will display a chart from google charts.

Items Working:

- Table row click to show child row
- Table displaying the first chart
- Correct data is being displayed in chart for that value

Items Not Working:

- Google Chart changing the data displayed on the next row being selected, when row is clicked, an empty space where the table should be appears.

PHP Code where I create my table, and populate it with data (comes from a sql db):

```
if( isset($db_graph_query)){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($db_graph_query)) {
        $rowcount2++;
        // removed the hard coded column set and made it driven off of the array below
        // could have pulled it from the $cols array above, but there might be columns that we don't wish to show
        echo "                                <tr>";
        $colindex = 0;
        foreach( $cols as $column_name ) {
            $style = "";
            $val = $row[$column_name];
            if ( isset($column_callback)) {
                $style=$column_callback($colindex, $val);
            }
            if($colindex == 0){ //make the first cell our toggle for child row
                echo "<td $style><a href='#' class='toggle' onClick='drawChart(\"$val\");'>$val</a></td>";
            } else {
                echo "<td $style>$val</td>";
            }
            $colindex++;
        }
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr class='tablesorter-childRow'>";
            echo "<td colspan='4'>";
                echo "<div id='chart_div' style='width: 1000px; height: 600px'></div>";
            echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

JavaScript to create my charts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    function drawChart(name) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Runs');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Fail');
            data.addRows([
                <?php
                    $dbName = "my_db";
                    $config = parse_ini_file("db_info.ini",true);
                    $dbUser = $config["DB"]["db_user"];
                    $dbServer = $config["DB"]["db_ip"];
                    $dbPassword = $config["DB"]["db_pass"];

                    $con = mysql_connect($dbServer, $dbUser, $dbPassword);

                    if (!$con) {
                        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                    }

                    mysql_select_db($dbName, $con);
                    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable");

                    $output = array();

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                        // create a temp array to hold the data
                        $temp = array();

                        // add the data
                        $temp[] = '"' . $row['Name'] . '"';
                        $temp[] = '"' . $row['Date'] . '"';
                        $temp[] = (int) $row['Runs'];
                        $temp[] = (int) $row['Fails'];
                        // implode the temp array into a comma-separated list and add to the output array
                        $output[] = '[' . implode(', ', $temp) . ']';
                    }
                    // implode the output into a comma-newline separated list and echo
                    echo implode(",\n", $output);

                    mysql_close($con);
                ?>
        ]);
        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        view.setRows(data.getFilteredRows([
            {column: 0, value: name} //I want this to be the value changed on row selection
        ]));
        view.setColumns([1,2,3]);

            var options = {
                hAxis: { 'title': 'Date' },
                width: 1000,
                height: 600,
                curveType: 'function',
                crosshair: { trigger: 'both'}
            };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(view, options);
    }

</script>
```

Output ( Name, Date, Runs, Fails are the columns, my text in the center got rearranged for some reason):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I realized was that the charts were stacking on top of each other inside of the first chart_div since they do not have unique identifiers for each container. So from there I just modified my php for the child row a bit to look like so:

Original:

```
echo "<tr class='tablesorter-childRow'>";
        echo "<td colspan='4'>";
            echo "<div id='chart_div' style='width: 1000px; height: 600px'></div>";
        echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
```

New & Improved:

```
echo "<tr class='tablesorter-childRow'>";
        echo "<td colspan='4'>";
            echo "<div id='$val' style='width: 1000px; height: 600px'></div>";
        echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
```